# ReactJS refresh URL changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a weird issue when refreshing a page in React.

it is adding a / to the end of the URL, which is causing a directory listing on the live server.

localhost:3000/projects when refreshed continues to show the same url

but when

localhost:3000/blog is refreshed it turns into localhost:3000/blog/

Has anybody come across this ?. Trying to find a place to start looking for a solution, as it only happens on this page.

Happy to post code here if needed.

This can be seen on the site [www.trevorrwarduk.me](http://www.trevorrwarduk.me) go to the blog and refresh.

App.js

```
var React                 = require('react');
var ReactRouter           = require('react-router-dom');
var Router                = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
var Route                 = ReactRouter.Route;
var Switch                = ReactRouter.Switch;
var BrowserHistory        = ReactRouter.BrowserHistory;

var HeadingSection        = require('./HeadingSection');
var Home                  = require('./Home');
var Projects              = require('./Projects');
var Me                    = require('./Me');
var Blog                  = require('./Blog');
var NotFound              = require('./NotFound');
var RightSideBar          = require('./RightSideBar');

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={BrowserHistory}>
        <div className="container greenBack">
          <div className="row headingArea">
            <HeadingSection />
          </div>
          <div className="row bottomArea">
            <div className="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div className="col-sm-10 contentArea">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path='/'          component={Home} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/projects'  component={Projects} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/me'        component={Me} />
                <Route exact={true} path='/blog'      component={Blog} />
                <Route path="/*"                      component={NotFound} status={404} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-1"><RightSideBar /></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = App;
```

htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you share some additional code? Are you using React Router?

Comment: Indeed I am ...

Comment: Can you share some of your router code?

Comment: all code can be seen on github ... https://github.com/Trevorrwarduk/React-Website if that helps?

Comment: Added the app.js code to the original ?.

Comment: Any `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Also, given it shows the directory listing the `/blog` directory exist on your server. Rename that to something other than `/blog`.

Comment: OH WT..... Yea it was the directory in public named blog. All working now Big thank you ... :)

Comment: Posting an answer to help others who come across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `/blog` is redirecting to `/blog/` and showing a directory listing, there must be a `/blog` directory already present on the server. When `/blog` is requested the server is serving the actual directory, instead of React Router handling the request.

Remove, or rename, the `/blog` directory on the server so React Router will handle the request.